# how to use the results of .load inside a replaceWith()

Tags: php, jquery

This is for a server status page using php and jquery. The page can be described as a table of appservers and webservers with empty cells where the status will appear on a button click. When clicking the button many instances of a servercheck.php script will be fired off asynchronously (the reason for using jquery instead of synchronous PHP-only) and the results are returned to the correct cell in the table according to the id of the td element.

All of which is kinda irrelevant other than background info.

So when the page first loads, a cell like this is waiting to be populated:

```
    <td id="a101-w01">&nbsp</td>
```

So I have a working .load() and example of which would be:

```
$("#a101-w01").load(\"singleServerCheck.php?&appserver=appservera&webserver=webserver1");
```

which would return something like:

```
<td id="a101-w01" class="up">Server UP</td>
```

I cant just use ("#a101-w01").load() because that only replaces the **contents** of the element, not the element itself (thus creating a cell inside the already existing cell instead)

What I want is this

```
<td id="a101-w01">&nbsp</td>
```

to be replaced with this

```
<td id="a101-w01" class="green">SERVER UP</td>
```

Urgh that was kinda hard to explain :) Anyway I have tried something like this:

```
$("#a101-w01").replaceWith().load(\"singleServerCheck.php?&appserver=appservera&webserver=webserver1");
```

and

```
$("#a101-w01").replaceWith(.load(\"singleServerCheck.php?&appserver=appservera&webserver=webserver1"));
```

but they are not right ... Can someone help this n00b to bring the two functions together?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `td` is not correct. I see what you are trying to do which is very simple. Try something like this.

Return just a string `"SERVER UP"` or `"SERVER DOWN"` from the server side and using that change add the required text and class

```
$.get("singleServerCheck.php?&appserver=appservera&webserver=webserver1", function(data){
     $('#a101-w01').html(data).addClass(data == "SERVER UP" ? "green" : "red");
});
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the modified answer and remove the down vote?

Comment: @Sean - Try this approach, it might help you.

Comment: You are right, it is simple which is why it's infuriating to have spent a couple of hours on it :)  I never gave a down vote but will vote up just to make sure :)

Comment: But back to the answer, it would work in some cases I am sure, but EVERYTHING about this setup is generated programatically due to the people who will updating this to work with new servers and combinations of servers are not able to program. Thus everything from the php code to the html to even the jquery instances themselves is all dynamically written according to a single config file which they can easily update. Thus the id's are all kinds of wierd references, which I could code around... but for something so simple it seems like a lot of work! Thanks though!

Comment: I tried it and it works nicely, though for what I needed to do in the end it was simpler to add the div. But I definitely accept this answer and will for sure use it in future - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can do this using `jQuery.get()`.

#### Sample

```
$.get("singleServerCheck.php?&appserver=appservera&webserver=webserver1", function(data) {
     $("#a101-w01").replaceWith(data);
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Thats what I said I already use (except you seem to have an extra closebracket on the end.) Because I am loading into a td element I end up with a cell within a cell.  The difficulty I guess is that I want to essentially change both the element's attributes and the contents of the element. I was hoping that by combining a .replaceWith and .load I would could do it in one swoop... but also open to answers about how to do it in two steps efficiently

Answer (score 0):

You could load more into the `<td>`:

```
<td id="a101-w01"><div class="up">Server UP</div></td>
```

Or check out the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and use the callback function.

Comment: So simple, it's stupid but works! My god, think I will go outside and shoot myself :) It has the desired effect, without answering the question - still think it should be possible to do what I asked perhaps with some 'normal' javascript to the object into a string or something I guess.

Comment: You can do it with the load callback very similar to ShankarSangoli solution or just use his code. But it does not work you you think it does because .load() is asynchron.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using the shorthand ajax function .load() because it inserts the result inside the element, and does not replace it.

Instead use the .get() function which has a bit more lengthy syntax, but gets the exact job done:

```
$.get('singleServerCheck.php',{appserver:'appservera',webserver:'webserver1'},function(data){
  $("#a101-w01").replaceWith(data)
})
```